# How do I adapt the `ap_uint` type so it can be used in a union?

Tags: c++, fpga, xilinx

```cpp
#ifndef _ENTRY
#define _ENTRY
#include <cstdint>
#include "ap_int.h"
struct US0 {
    ap_uint<1> tag;
    union {
        struct {
            ap_uint<2l> v0;
        } case1; // Some
    };
};
US0 US0_0() { // None
    US0 x;
    x.tag = 0;
    return x;
}
US0 US0_1(ap_uint<2l> v0) { // Some
    US0 x;
    x.tag = 1;
    x.case1.v0 = v0;
    return x;
}
int32_t entry(){
    ap_uint<2l> v0;
    v0 = 0;
    US0 v1;
    v1 = US0_1(v0);
    return 0l;
}
#endif
```

I am working on compiling a functional language to the C++ backend for FPGAs, and after much debugging, I've finally realized that the compiler is refusing to place the `ap_uint` in an union. I get a lot of deleted type errors in the console if I try to compile a program like this.

```
../../../../hello.hpp: In function 'US0 US0_0()':
../../../../hello.hpp:22:9: error: use of deleted function 'US0::US0()'
     US0 x;
         ^
../../../../hello.hpp:13:8: note: 'US0::US0()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 struct US0 {
        ^~~
../../../../hello.hpp:18:11: error: union member 'US0::<anonymous union>::case1' with non-trivial 'US0::<anonymous union>::<anonymous struct>::<constructor>()'
         } case1; // Some
           ^~~~~
```

How do I adapt the [ap types](https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1399-vitis-hls/Arbitrary-Precision-AP-Data-Types) so they can be used in union types.

Comment: The arbitrary precision datatype from the Xilinx library. The user guide mentions that unlike regular C++ types it is not initialized.

Comment: See what happens to `union`s when they contain members that have one or more special member functions (constructor etc) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union  _"...If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function ... that function is deleted by default in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer."_

Comment: Do you have any good references for how this could be done? If possible, I'd like it to just default to the C semantics and copy everything from the right to left side.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. C++ has various rules around resource management that C doesn't that need to be taken care of. I'll have to output the constructors as well as the assignment ops to ensure they are followed.

Comment: Can you show the source for the `ap_uint` class? Or post a link to it?

Comment: I think it is this: https://github.com/Xilinx/HLS_arbitrary_Precision_Types/blob/master/include/ap_int.h

Comment: I looked around the code and found [this](https://github.com/Xilinx/HLS_arbitrary_Precision_Types/blob/master/include/etc/ap_private.h#L3303) (a constructor of some base class of `ap_uint`, and also [this function](https://github.com/Xilinx/HLS_arbitrary_Precision_Types/blob/master/include/etc/ap_private.h#L2100)). I initially assumed the constructor doesn't do anything, and isn't marked `=default` by mistake, but apparently it does do something, so putting it into a plain union could be unsafe (the compiler doesn't want to do that for a reason). Can you use `std::variant` instead?

Comment: No, the C++ support by the HLS compiler goes only up to 14. Since it is for FPGAs, I do not want to try importing boost either. It is not a problem. Now that I understand what the issue is, I'll just program the compiler to generate the necessary cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef _ENTRY
#define _ENTRY
#include <cstdint>
#include "ap_int.h"

struct US0 {
    ap_uint<1> tag;
    union U {
        struct {
            ap_uint<2l> v0;
        } case1; // Some
        U() {}
    } v;
    US0() {}
    US0(const US0 && x) {
        this->tag = x.tag;
        this->v.case1 = x.v.case1;
    }
    US0 & operator=(US0 & x) {
        this->tag = x.tag;
        this->v.case1 = x.v.case1;
        return *this;
    }
    US0 & operator=(US0 && x) {
        this->tag = x.tag;
        this->v.case1 = x.v.case1;
        return *this;
    }
};
US0 US0_0() { // None
    US0 x;
    x.tag = 0;
    return x;
}
US0 US0_1(ap_uint<2l> v0) { // Some
    US0 x;
    x.tag = 1;
    x.v.case1.v0 = v0;
    return x;
}
int32_t entry(){
    ap_uint<2l> v0;
    v0 = 0;
    US0 v1;
    v1 = US0_1(v0);
    return 0l;
}
#endif
```

The suggestion by Richard in the comment was right. The way to make it work would be to define the various constructors as well as assignment the operators for this datatype. Here is an example of how it could be done. The next step would be to automate them.

Comment: It should be `US0(const US0 & x)` and `US0 & operator=(const US0 & x)`. `US0 & operator=(US0 && x)` looks unnecessary.

Comment: No actually, it seems the `US0 & operator=(US0 && x)` is the one that is necessary. I can get rid of the first one, but not it. As for `US0(const US0 && x)`, I can replace it with `US0(const US0 & x)`, but I need one of them so I'll stick with the `&&` version.

Comment: Are you saying that if you replace `US0(const US0 && x)` with `US0(const US0 & x)`, and both `operator=` with a single `US0 & operator=(const US0 & x)`, it doesn't work? It should. Why I'm saying this is: 1. It's strange to have mismatching `operator=` and copy/move constructors, and 2. It's strange to have something other than a `const T &` and/or `T &&` constructor/assignment. `T &` and `const T &&` are almost never used as parameters to those. If you still want to keep your version, I would test that constructing and assigning both const and non-const, both lvalues and rvalues still works.